# Wordpress: How to Hook into get_the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filter, hook

I am looking for a proper way to hook into `get_the_content` method in Wordpress. Wordpress provide hooks for `the_content`, `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()` but not for `get_the_content()`. I  have a plugin which I maintain that appends and prepends some HTML in the content post. 
I used the same for `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()`. What should I do to support `get_the_content()` as well as I see most themes now use `get_the_content()`? ie.: if the theme is using `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`, my plugin fails.

My plugin code is the following:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');

function my_init() {
  add_filter('the_content', 'my_method', 12);
  add_filter('get_the_content', 'my_method', 12);
}


function my_method($content) {
  $content = "blah blah".$content."blah blah";

  return $content;
}
```

The above code (in my plugin) listens to `the_content call` from the theme and add my own content to the article.

Assume this is the method in a theme file:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

It works properly in the above case.

But if the theme code is something like this (Note the change from the_content() to `get_the_content())`.

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <?php echo get_the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

My plugin fails as there is no hooks defined for `get_the_content`. As I am not in control of theme code, the solution which Wordpress explains in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) doesn't help for me:

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

Update: Problem definition expanded for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

According to the codex:

> If you use plugins that filter content (add_filter('the_content')),
> then this will not apply the filters, unless you call it this way
> (using apply_filters):

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

Its documented here in the [**wordpress codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).

### EDITED

Try using output buffering to put `the_content` in a variable.

That way you dont have to worry about `get_the_content`

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$newContent = ob_get_clean();
```

Now its stored in a variable called `$newContent` easy for you to manipulate.

Comment: I have checked that. But it seems more like something the theme developers have to do when they call get_the_content() method. I am not sure whether this can be used in my case.

Comment: you said you are using a plugin and it applies to the plugins case, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried that and failed. I guess it applies to plugins which wants to modify the content using get_the_content() method and but not to loose the filters attached to the_content hook. In my case, I am looking at themes which use get_the_content as their method to print content on page and I want to pass the content through my method which I have defined in my plugin file. I am sorry if I have confused you.

Comment: I have expanded my problem definition further. Hopes it's clear now.

Comment: That's something I haven't considered so far! Let me try that!

Comment: @SrijithVijayamohan i added a brief example in my edited answer just incase.

Comment: Well, seems like it wont work in my case. I need a proper hook and pass back the content to the theme file. My plugin is not the right place to echo the content back to the stream.

Comment: why not overwrite the content with the output buffer? use output buffer inside of your add_filter?

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear on that. Can you help with the sample code I have provided. Please note that I am not inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick (note `my_post` there):

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');

function my_init() {
  add_filter('the_content', 'my_method', 12);
  add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_method', 12);
  add_filter('the_post', 'my_post');
}

function my_post($post) {
  $post->post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
  $post->post_content = get_the_content();
  return $post;
}

function my_method($content) {
  $content = "blah blah".$content."blah blah";
  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Just Try With The Following :***

***Example With Cform:***

```
add_filter('get_the_content', 'cforms_insert',10);
```

For Your [Reference](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-forum/troubleshooting/fix-the_content-vs-get_the_content/)

(or)

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$panels = explode("[newpage]", $content);
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: `add_filter('get_the_content', 'my_method',10);`

This didn't work for me. Do they really have a hook 'get_the_content'. Couldn't find it in [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) either. 

The second option, as I am not handling the theme end, I am helpless. If the user use a theme without the mentioned code, it fails.

Comment: I believe 'get_the_content' filter does not exist now in 6.3 wp version and really not sure that it exists before